# How can I pass <input> value into controller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a custom input field that acts as a drop-down menu and it works like this:

[image: Custom Drop-down menu]

Each option is an `<input>` field and I need the value of this input to be passed into the controller. The `<input>` looks like this:

```html
<!-- Updated -->
<label for="United States">United States</label>
<input type="radio" class="radio" id="United States" name="country" value="United States">
```

When the user presses the continue button, I want the value of the `<input>` to be passed to my controller: `WelcomeController`.

-- Updated --
My controller method looks like this:

```
public function countrySelect(Request $request)
{
    $country = $request->input('country');

    dd($country);
}
```

Here is a basic code structure of the inputs - I think I should be using a form and so have created a route in `web.php`:

```php
Route::post('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController::class, 'countrySelect'])->name('CS');
```

And that the input should have the `value` property:

```html
<!-- Updated -->
<form action="{{ route('CS') }}" method="POST">
    
    <input name="country" value="[COUNTRY Value]">

    <button type="submit"> CONTINUE </button>
</form>
```

The `countrySelect` method in my controller is empty and so how do I pass the value of the `<input>` into it? Thanks!

---

My Full Form:

```html
<form action="{{ route('CS') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="country-select-container">
        <div class="country-align-container">
            <div class="CountryInput">
                <div class="select-box">
                    <div class="options-container">
                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="United States">United States</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="United States">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="United Kingdom And Ireland">United Kingdom And Ireland</label>
                             <input type="radio" class="radio" id="United Kingdom And Ireland" name="country" value="United Kingdom And Ireland">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Philippines">Philippines</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Philippines">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="India">India</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="India">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Indonesia">Indonesia</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Indonesia">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Malaysia">Malaysia</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Malaysia">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Mexico">Mexico</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Mexico">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Singapore">Singapore</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="Singapore">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Germany">Germany</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Germany">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Brazil">Brazil</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Brazil">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Canada">Canada</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Canada">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Italy">Italy</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Italy">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Colombia">Colombia</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Colombia">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Australia">Australia</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Australia">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="South Africa">South Africa</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="South Africa">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="France">France</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="France">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Pakistan">Pakistan</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Pakistan">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Bangladesh">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Spain">Spain</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Spain">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="United Arab Emirates">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Netherlands">Netherlands</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Netherlands">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Sri Lanka">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Russia">Russia</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Russia">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Trinidad & Tobago">Trinidad & Tobago</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Trinidad & Tobago">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Saudi Arabia">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Thailand">Thailand</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Thailand">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Peru">Peru</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Peru">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="New Zealand">New Zealand</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="New Zealand">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Vietnam">Vietnam</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Vietnam">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Japan">Japan</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Japan">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Egypt">Egypt</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Egypt">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Argentina">Argentina</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Argentina">
                        </div>

                        <div class="option">
                            <label for="Other">Other...</label>
                            <input type="radio" name="country" value="Other...">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="selected">
                        Select Country To Continue:
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="guest-action-container">
            <div class="go-back-container">
                <div class="go-back-btn">
                    <span class="go-back">
                        <span class="go-back-icon"></span>
                        <span class="go-back-text">BACK</span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="continue-to-site-container">
                <div class="continue-to-site-btn">
                    <button type="submit" class="continue-to-site">
                        <span class="continue-text">CONTINUE</span>
                        <span class="continue-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="clearFix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the JS that creates the dropdown effect:

```
// country select drop down
$(document).ready(function(){
    // country select options
    const selected = document.querySelector(".selected");
    const optionsContainer = document.querySelector(".options-container");
    const optionsList = document.querySelectorAll(".option");

    selected.addEventListener("click", () => {
        optionsContainer.classList.toggle("active");
    });

    optionsList.forEach( o => {
        o.addEventListener("click", () => {
            selected.innerHTML = o.querySelector("label").innerHTML;
            optionsContainer.classList.remove("active");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: @TimLewis I have made these changes, but when I `dd($request->input('country'))`, I get a null returned. I have updated the code to show what I have now

Comment: @TimLewis I updated it there

Comment: So now you have two inputs with the name `country`, which one are you trying to send to the Controller? Also, the 2nd `input` should probably be `<input type="hidden" name="country" value="">`, and when you click a radio option, us JS to update that to `value="{js logic to set value to 'United States'}"`, then it should work (at least that's how I'd approach this).

Comment: @TimLewis I am unsure of what you mean, I have added my entire form to give you a better idea

Comment: Ah ok, so the way you posted your code, it looked like two separate inputs, but in your update, that isn't the case. When you select a `radio`, it should set `checked` on that `<input>`, which should send the value to the Controller. If that isn't happening, you might have some JS that is interfering with that. Sidenote, try to post the full code, or an accurate snippet from the start :)

Comment: @TimLewis aww okay, I see where the confusion is now, and oh it looks like that could be the issue, I have updated my question to include my JS that creates the drop-down effect, could you help with the use of JS to set as checked

Comment: @TimLewis I figured it out, thank you!

Comment: Awesome! Apologies, I didn't have a chance to look it over following your edit, but glad you got it working! If you'd like, you can add an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start by changing the code of the form from:

```
<form action="{{ route('CS') }}" method="POST">
    
    <input value="country">

    <button type="submit"> CONTINUE </button>
</form
```

to

```
<form action="{{ route('CS') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <input value="country" name="country">

    <button type="submit"> CONTINUE </button>
</form>
```

I hope that you are seeing the difference. while using a form in laravel you must add the csrf token, if not it will not work.
After that in your controller just write:

```
public function handleSubmission(Request $request)
{
   $country = $request->input('country');
}
```

Comment: edit and use code insertion instead of snippet, it does not work as its laravel

Comment: I was already using @csrf, I've added my full form to the question

Comment: what did you get as a output for this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to pass the value of an input to your controller you should start by having a "name" parameter in your input, then a POST route, in your web.php file, that calls the method in the controller that should get the values. Finally use request('name-of-input') and that should return the value.

Example:

view:

```
<form action="/user" class="admin-form" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <label for="form-name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="form-name" name="name" required>

            <label for="form-email">Email: </label>
            <input type="email" id="form-email" name="email" required>

            <input id="form-submit" type="submit" value="Sign up!">
 </form>
```

web.php:

```
Route::post('/user', 'App\Http\Controllers\UserController@store');
```

controller:

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User();
    $user->name = request('name');
    $user->email = request('email');
    $user->save();
    return redirect('/user/create');
}
```

Comment: That didn't work, see my updated question

Comment: @RossCurrie are you using a form to send the Post request? if you dont use a form you should use AJAX, but in this case a form would be enough

Comment: Yes I am using a Form, I will update question with full code

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `name` attribute in the input field like this:

```html
<form action="{{ route('CS') }}" method="POST">
    
    <input name="country" value="country">

    <button type="submit"> CONTINUE </button>
</form
```

Then in the controller action you can reference the `name` field like this:

```php
public function handleSubmission(Request $request)
{
   $country = $request->input('country');
}
```

Comment: For query parameters, pass them as `/url/path?query_param=value`, and retrieve them with `$request->query('query_param')`

Comment: `$request->input()` will work for both `GET` (query string) and `POST` methods to retrieve input :)

Comment: That was the same as Tim's response @elchroy, see my updated question